# Need Clarification for sharepoint search

Tags: web-services, sharepoint, search, scope

I have done the python application to search the SharePoint content using SharePoint web services. Here I am using search query to filter the data based on the scope. For enterprise search i am using search.asmx to get the data.

My doubt is I need to use search.asmx to search the data inside the particular list? Or I can use CAML query and list.asmx combination will give the list level search data ( In this case content search is not possible)
 Is there any idea to implement the search methods?
Site collection scope: search.asmx
Site level scope: search.asmx
List level scope: lists.asmx and getlistitem with filtered CAML query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using SharePoint 2010, the addition of wildcard property search allows you to formulate a query using the Path property
e.g.

test Path:http://SharePoint2010/sites/examplelib/*

Which will allow you to use the normal search within a list.

The lists.asmx will not give you the same results as "search" would as the lists.asmx does not "search" the contents of the documents.

However I am pretty sure having spaces in your Path will prevent you from using this approach.

Comment: Thats fine. By default sharepoint use contains or free test query?. also it usees wildcard search by default? how the sharepoint identify that to use wildcard search while keywork has the * or ?.

Comment: By default it uses a keyword search. Contains/Free text is only available via the webservice.